# Facebook Share Attachment Failing

Tags: html, facebook, http

Please help.  I cannot get the Share Attachment to work for this folder on my webserver, others are working.

When using the FB OG Debugger
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

I get the following 
Object at URL 'http://www.coldkatana.com/DCRockers/Showcase20160430/index.html' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.

If I try using URL without the 'index.html'  the FB OG Debugger says that it is getting a 206 response code.  but the page appears to serve just fine to all of my browsers.   I am stumped!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.coldkatana.com%2FDCRockers%2FShowcase20160430%2F - that's all the FB scraper gets to see (a mostly empty HTML document, that contains no OG meta data whatsoever, and only a single paragraph element with what looks like a mis-handled BOM as content.). Why, you need to find out. Start by checking server access & error log. Investigate, if anything in/on your system might have taken upon itself the task of blocking “bots” – and gone overboard while doing so.

Comment: Why you need to redirect or use an index.html url? As a far as I know, Facebook don't generate the index.html files because take the original url without index.html to the end. So, when you re debugging, facebook says:

Answer (score 0):

You have to describe all properties of the image, like:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/ogp.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/ogp.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
```

Please visit this page for more about it. http://ogp.me/

Comment: Adding these additional image properties did not change anything.